Why is a process slower inside an audio interrupt/callback compared to a loop?
I'm writing a real-time audio application in C++ that does a beefy amount of processing on 10ms chunks of audio. I'm using miniaudio to handle the audio I/O. When benchmarking the amount of time the processing takes, i.e. recording the numbers from the following inside the callback function:
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
process_audio(input, output);
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

float elapsed_microseconds = (float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();

a single process usually takes around 2.5ms, but occasionally down to 1.7ms and up to 4ms.
However, if I do the exact same thing in a non-real-time scenario (i.e. loading an audio file and processing it in a for loop without an interrupt/callback function) I get numbers solidly around 1.8ms, with very little variance.
At first I thought it might be an OS thing, but I'm seeing the same thing on Windows, Mac, and Linux. I also thought it could be something to do with miniaudio, but the same thing happens using RtAudio as well.
What is causing this to be slower and more unpredictable inside the callback function, and is there anything I can do to improve it?
EDIT: Here's a minimal example:
// https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio
#define MINIAUDIO_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "miniaudio.h"

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

ma_device_config m_mic_path_config;
ma_device m_mic_device;

int discardCount;
float average_execution_time_usec;
float max_execution_time_usec;
float min_execution_time_usec;
int samples_collected;

float temp = 0;

void zero_vars() {
    discardCount = 0;
    average_execution_time_usec = 0.0f;
    max_execution_time_usec = 0;
    min_execution_time_usec = 1000000;
    samples_collected = 0;
}

void log_measurement(float elapsed_microseconds) {
    // Discard measurements during the first second
    if (discardCount < 10){
        discardCount++;
    }
    else {

        average_execution_time_usec += elapsed_microseconds;
        if (elapsed_microseconds > max_execution_time_usec){
            max_execution_time_usec = elapsed_microseconds;
        }
        if (elapsed_microseconds < min_execution_time_usec){
            min_execution_time_usec = elapsed_microseconds;
        }

        samples_collected++;

    }
}


void print_stats() {

    printf("Min execution time: %0.2f\n", min_execution_time_usec);
    printf("Average execution time: %0.2f\n", average_execution_time_usec / (float) samples_collected);
    printf("Max execution time: %0.2f\n", max_execution_time_usec);
    printf("Samples collected: %d\n", samples_collected);

}

float beefy_process(float num) {

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++){
        num = num * 1.55;
        num = num + 5;
        num = num / 2.3;
    }

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    float elapsed_microseconds = (float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();

    log_measurement(elapsed_microseconds);
    return num;
}


void microphone_callback(ma_device* pDevice, void* pOutput, const void* pInput, ma_uint32 frameCount) {    
    temp += beefy_process(5);
}

int start_microphone() {
    ma_result result;

    m_mic_path_config = ma_device_config_init(ma_device_type_capture);
    m_mic_path_config.sampleRate = 48000;
    m_mic_path_config.pUserData = nullptr;
    m_mic_path_config.capture.pDeviceID = NULL; /* system default microphone */
    m_mic_path_config.capture.format = ma_format_s16;
    m_mic_path_config.capture.channels = 1;
    m_mic_path_config.capture.shareMode = ma_share_mode_shared;
    m_mic_path_config.dataCallback = microphone_callback;
    result = ma_device_init(NULL, &m_mic_path_config, &m_mic_device);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to set up microphone path. Error: %d", result);
        assert(0);
        return result;
    }

    result = ma_device_start(&m_mic_device);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start microphone path. Error: %d", result);
        assert(0);
        return result;
    }

    return 0;
}



int stop_microphone() {
    ma_result result = ma_device_stop(&m_mic_device);
    if (result != MA_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to stop microphone path. Error: %d", result);
        assert(0);
        return result;
    }

    ma_device_uninit(&m_mic_device);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("NON-REALTIME:\n");

    zero_vars();

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
        temp += beefy_process(5);
    }
    
    print_stats();
    printf("%f\n", temp); //prevents compiler from optimizing away beefy_process
    

    printf("\nREALTIME:\n");

    zero_vars();

    start_microphone();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3 * 1000));
    stop_microphone();

    print_stats();
    printf("%f\n", temp);
    
    return 0;
}

From this I get the following result:
NON-REALTIME:
Min execution time: 2004.00
Average execution time: 2494.63
Max execution time: 2987.00
Samples collected: 290
1999.995239

REALTIME:
Min execution time: 2551.00
Average execution time: 3893.67
Max execution time: 4362.00
Samples collected: 291
4006.685547



Are you compiling with compiler optimisations enabled? 2) Are you compiling with link time optimisations (LTO) enabled? 3) Don't use high_resolution_clock for timing - see the notes at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock - use steady_clock. 4) Can you post a [mre]?



yes 2) no 3/4) thanks for the heads up on the clock. I will put together a minimal example using steady_clock


Obvious  question: why not hand off from your callback to another thread?  That's what I do.  Or is that inconvenient?  The overhead of a thread switch is probably better than what you're seeing now.

@JesperJuhl I've added a reproducible example. Please take a look whenever you get the chance :)

@catnip I'm not sure I understand. My understanding is the callback function is being called in its own thread already (separate from the main thread). Wouldn't handing off to a third thread be redundant?

Side note: You do know that assert() does nothing in release builds, right?

Side note. In windows, use ASIO. That is the best way for real time.

@nukelash Well, I'm not sure what's happening here but your results indicate that it is worth trying.

My (wild) guess is that you're seeing the effects of RAM caching, or lack thereof.  That is, in your non-real-time loop, the first iteration of the loop drags all of the relevant pages of RAM into the CPU's cache, and all the subsequent iterations of the loop benefit from having the pages they need already on-CPU so they never have to wait for DRAM fetches.  With the real-time-callback, OTOH, unrelated code is executing between callbacks and sometimes pushing "your pages" out of the cache, so the next callback sometimes has to wait while they page back in again.

@JeremyFriesner thanks for your comment, that was originally my thought as well. However, I would think the time added by a cache miss would be the same whether beefy_process() is 200000 loops or 5 loops. But if I make beefy_process() shorter, by say lowering the loop by a factor of 10, the MIN, MAX, and AVG times all also lower by a factor of 10. This tells me that the actual processing speed of the process is slower, as opposed to some additional work (like a cache miss) happening at the beginning
